# Selenium - Unable to Locate Element even after verifying

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

This has worked fine for months, but throws errors now. It's a pretty simple code: open Chrome and pull an element out. It's now telling me that it's unable to locate the element.

I've inspected the element with the Chrome window open and verify the XPATH and it matches to what is in the code exactly. I've taken a screenshot of the page it's running on and it all looks fine.

What am I missing?

[image]

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import webbrowser
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time

site_lat = 34.29421
site_lon = -97.44667

def watershed_lookup(site_lat, site_lon):
    op=webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    #op.add_argument('--headless')
    op.add_argument('window-size=1920x1080')

    url_water = 'https://mywaterway.epa.gov/community/'+str(site_lon)+','+str(site_lat)+'/overview'

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options = op)
    driver.get(url_water)
    time.sleep(3)
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"root\"]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/p[2]")           
    start1 = 'WATERSHED: '
    end1 = '('
    end2 = ')'
    s = element.text

    watershed_name = s[s.find(start1)+len(start1):s.rfind(end1)]
    watershed_id = s[s.find(end1)+len(end1):s.rfind(end2)]

    print("Watershed Name: " + watershed_name)
    print("Watershed ID: " + watershed_id)
    driver.close()


watershed_lookup(site_lat, site_lon)
```

Comment: Post the complete error message. It works fine for me.

Comment: Can you convert this url and provide the one you are using ? for me it is redirecting to new the mail page where I could not find that xpath.

Comment: The exact error it's throwing is selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="root"]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/p[2]"}

Comment: The URL it's targeting in this example is https://mywaterway.epa.gov/community/-97.44667,34.29421/overview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Xpath that you are using is an absolute Xpath, try finding that element using a relative Xpath. I have seen absolute xpaths working using dev tools and failing during run time.
Use explicit wait until that element is visible/interactable and then verify.

Comment: Bingo. Used the SelectorsHub Chrome extension to find the relative Xpath instead of the absolute and it works again. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

May its because you have not put any waits.

Either apply Implicit wait :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options = op)
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
driver.get(url_water)
...
```

Or apply Explicit Wait:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

...
driver.get(url_water)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,20)
ele = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//*[@id=\"root\"]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/p[2]")))
print(ele.text)
```

Comment: Using explicit wait, it can't find the element and just times out. For some reason even though the XPATH is matching up, it's not seeing it.